# What is the best practice in Java to set a constant required in subclasses?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following situation:

- A parent class has a function that depends on a constant. But the only valid place to define that constant is in subclasses (parent class cannot define the constant's value, but it can be used with the constant undefined in 99% of use cases - the constant is a default to use if a specific configuration element is missing).
- However, I would like to enforce that any child class inheriting from that parent class **must** define the value for the constant, since any child classes have to be able to use the other 1% of functionality.

**What is the best practice to implement this enforcement in Java, ideally at compile time?** (clearly, at runtime, I can simply check if the constant is null/empty in the method using it).

My own solution was to implement a value-getter for the constant as an abstract method in the parent class, and call that in combination with the real setter in the constructor; something like this:

```
   public class HelperClass1 {
       private String myConstant; 
       public void setMyConstant() {} // implemented obviousy
       public void myMethod() { // Called from ParentClass's methods
           // Do something useful with myConstant
       }
    }

   import HelperClass1;
   public abstract class ParentClass {
       ParentClass() {
           HelperClass1.setMyConstant( getMyConstantValue() );
       }

       public abstract void getMyConstantValue();
   }

   public class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass {
       public void getMyConstantValue() { return "BUZZ"; }
   }

   public class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass {
   }  // Fails to compile without getMyConstantValue()
```

However, (a) This implementation has a problem (I can't use ParentClass itself, since it's now abstract) without subclassing; and (b) since I'm not a Java developer, I'm afraid that this isn't the best or the most elegant solution. So I'd like to know if there's a best practices approach that improves on what I implemented.

Comment: Could you give any background information, anything that would explain your unusual requirements? There is a chance that this is an XY Problem in disguise, but it's currently hard to tell.

Comment: You can also look into interfaces, which require method definitions.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - since 80% of code is common to all child classes and can be implemented in the parent class, what's the point of using an interface vs. abstract class?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - These aren't "requirements". They are my design goals. The background is in first paragraph - I need to put in a default value to use in case a specific value is missing from a configuration file. That configuration default ONLY makes sense in the context of child classes, so I have to make sure any child class defines one.

Comment: What if you ask your parent class to retrieve the configured value in the `getMyConstantValue()` method? If I get you well that's what the parent class must use?

Comment: Why do you need `HelperClass1`? Why can't `myConstant` be a field of `ParentClass`? What am I missing?

Comment: @DVK a little bit background information would be appreciated. By the information given, i would say this is broken by design, but this is more a guess than a statement. Your subclasses should know their default values and thus should be able to report a sensible value to your super class by a common getter (which the super class can implement, returning its own default value)

Comment: @Turing85 - that's the problem. Super class cannot implement ANY sensible default value, and therefore implementing the getter in the super class would be contrary to my need (to make sure subclasses implement valid default, catchable at compile time). Your suggestion would lead to a possible bug where child class forgets to implement the default, and inherits a dummy one from parent.

Comment: @DVK, will you be creating instances of the parent class directly? If not, then there shouldn't be a problem in declaring the parent `abstract` because you can also have non-abstract methods in an `abstract` class in Java.

Comment: All you need to do is get rid of `HelperClass1` and give `ParentClass` only one constructor (taking a `String`). Then all subclasses will be forced to use `super(whatever)`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic - IDEALLY, I'd like to be able to create instances of parent class. That's one reason I don't like my "abstract" solution. But if there's a consensus that any other solution is worse, I can live with the pain (or simply create a "dummy" child class that implenents a dummy default value)

Comment: @DVK then let the getter-method of the superclass throw an Exception when it is called. The getter of the child-classes must then be annotated with a `throws`, but do not need to throw an exception. As soon as the getter of the super class is called, an exception will be risen and you can react accordingly.

Comment: See this, may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988294/how-to-define-constants-final-variables-in-abstract-superclasses-but-assign-them

Comment: @Turing85 - throwing an exception is run time , not compile time. If I want that, there's a much simpler solution, throw an exception where you use the constant in Helper class.

Comment: You could also make a new abstract class called AbstractParentClass. Make ParentClass final, not abstract,and subclass AbstractParentClass. Child classes subclass AbstractParentClass instead, but ParentClass cannot be subclassed.

Answer (score 5):

Provide two constructors for the parent class:

1. One is a protected constructor which takes the constant as an argument.
2. The other is private constructor which can construct instances of the parent class without setting the constant.

Provide a factory method for the parent class which can call the private no-constant constructor.

Classes that want to get an instance of the parent class can call the factory method. But child classes that want to inherit from the parent class have to call the protected constructer, which can validate that a valid constant was passed.

```
public class ParentClass {

    private final SomeClass myConstant;

    protected ParentClass(SomeClass aConstant) {
        if (null == aConstant) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }
        myConstant = aConstant;
    }

    private ParentClass() {
        myConstant = null;
    }

    public static ParentClass getInstance() {
        return new ParentClass();
    }
}


public class ChildClass {

    public ChildClass() {
        super(new SomeClass(42));
    }
}
```

This isn't perfect. Someone could write a child class that passes a bad constant to the superclass constructor, and it wouldn't actually fail until some code tried to construct an instance of the child class.

Comment: Who is downvoting all these answers without explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure that **any** solution would be able to address the last problem. So +1 from me - it seems elegant enough from my non-java-expert eyes.

Comment: @pbabcdefp those answers are bad and deserve to be downvoted. This one, on the other hand, provides a better approach.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza My main point was the "without explanation" bit. I hate that (although I am guilty of it sometimes too). I put my comment with this answer as I agree it's the best one (I upvoted too).

Comment: Nice solution. If  `SomeClass` were an `enum`, then you would have better compile-time type safety and it would eliminate the "bad constant" problem.