# why can't this be static?

Tags: java, static, subclass

```
package com.evansgame.newproject.fps;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.*;
abstract class Weapon{
  int weaponID;//why can't this be static?
  DrawMe drawMe;//why can't this be static?
  int itemID;
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  static ReentrantLock weaponsLock = new ReentrantLock();
  static LinkedList<Weapon> weapons = new LinkedList<>();
  boolean active = true;
  Weapon(int itemID, float x, float y, float z){
    this.itemID = itemID;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
  static class Bazoooka extends Weapon{
    static final int WEAPON_ID = 0;
    static final DrawMe bazoookaDrawMe = DrawMe.colorClone(DrawMe.loadModel("bazoooka"),0,.1f,.8f,1,0,.2f);
    Bazoooka(int itemID, float x, float y, float z){
      super(itemID,x,y,z);
      drawMe = bazoookaDrawMe;//same across all Bazoookas
      weaponID = 0;//same across all Bazoookas
    }
  }
}
```

Variables weaponID and drawMe are to be the same across all Bazoooka instances. When I'm accessing instances of Weapon I need the weaponID and DrawMe for whatever type of weapon it happens to be. It feels like these variables are static why do I have to use instance variables for them?

Comment: If you make it static, then its value will be the same for all **Weapons** not just all Bazooka instances, so it's not a good idea.

Comment: I'm wondering if you want to use an enum for some of your constants.

Comment: But all the subclasses are to have these same static fields that are static to the subclasses. Is there a way I can put this definition into the abstract superclass?

Comment: You can define the instance variable weaponID as final in the abstract class and initialize it in the constructor of the subclass. In this way, it is guaranteed that it will always have the same value for any instance of the subclass and is never altered afterwards. Note that you need to define the constructor of the abstract class as well (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988294/how-to-define-constants-final-variables-in-abstract-superclasses-but-assign-them).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels To my surprise I did end up using an enum!

Answer (score 1):

You could use getters instead of just fields:

```
abstract class Weapon {
    abstract int getID();
    abstract DrawMe getDrawMe();
    ...
}
```

Then in the Bazooka class you just override those methods like:

```
static final int WEAPON_ID = 0;
static final DrawMe bazoookaDrawMe = DrawMe.colorClone(DrawMe.loadModel("bazoooka"),0,.1f,.8f,1,0,.2f);

@Override
int getID() {
    return WEAPON_ID;
}

@Override
DrawMe getDrawMe() {
    return bazoookaDrawMe;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option: give the abstract class a `abstract public int getId();` method declaration. Let each sub-type override this returning its own static field result. But the static field should be declared in the subclass not the abstract parent.

```
public abstract class Weapon {
    public abstract int getId();
    public abstract DrawMe getDrawMe();    

    // .... other fields
}
```

```
public class Bazooka extends Weapon {

    private static final int BAZOOKA_ID = 200;
    private DrawMe drawMe;

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return BAZOOKA_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public DrawMe getDrawMe() {
        if (drawMe == null) {
            drawMe = new BazookaDrawMe();
        }
        return drawMe;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an enum

```
package com.evansgame.newproject.fps;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.*;
class Weapon{
  static enum WeaponEnum{
    NO_WEAPON(0, new DrawMe(),Player.loadAnimation("standing"),Player.loadAnimation("run"))
    ,BAZOOOKA(1, DrawMe.colorClone(DrawMe.loadModel("bazoooka"),0,.1f,.8f,1,0,.2f),Player.loadAnimation("standWithBazoooka"),Player.loadAnimation("runWithBazoooka"));
    final int WEAPON_ID;
    final DrawMe DRAW_ME;
    final Moment[] STANDING_ANIMATION;
    final Moment[] RUNNING_ANIMATION;
    WeaponEnum(int id, DrawMe d, Moment[] standingAnimation, Moment[] runningAnimation){
      WEAPON_ID = id;
      DRAW_ME = d;
      STANDING_ANIMATION = standingAnimation;
      RUNNING_ANIMATION = runningAnimation;
    }
  }
  static ReentrantLock weaponsLock = new ReentrantLock();
  static LinkedList<Weapon> weapons = new LinkedList<>();
  WeaponEnum weaponType;
  int itemID;
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
  boolean active = true;
  Weapon(WeaponEnum weaponType, int itemID, float x, float y, float z){
    this.weaponType = weaponType;
    this.itemID = itemID;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}
```